# Animating Wpf Windows Transitions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

How can I animate the window elements in my application when showing them and closing them or switching between windows?

Answer (score 1):

Using Control templates set Triggers on properties you wish to provide animations for to fire off a storyboard. You might check out [this article](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1028-wpf-tutorial-styles-triggers-and-animations-7.aspx) or one like it. Or you can fire off a storyboard when a window becomes Active which there's also articles out there for like [this one](http://www.joeseymour.net/2009/07/wpf-screen-transition.html) but a quick search for something like ["WPF Animation"](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf%20animation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) should provide a lot of places to start depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to animate a Window. However it's possible you do not enjoy the acceleration and ease that comes with other elements as, as far as I know, those elements are inside WPF while Windows are part of the OS. It's possible you end messing with OS's APIs.